# How Implement matrix equation in R?

Tags: r, math, matrix, optimization, equation

I'm studying 'Latent Aspect Rating Analysis' and
I'm trying to implement the method in r.
But I have no idea how to solve those in r programming.

Here is the equation:
[image: the equation]

Here is the [r](/questions/tagged/r) code so far:

```
-(t( alpha ) %*% Sd - rd) / delta) * Sd - sigma %*% (alpha - mu)
```

I have to figure out the alpha which makes this equation to zero.
Delta and rd is constant, alpha, Sd and mu are matrix ( k x 1 ).
And sigma is a matrix (k x k ). In this case, k = 3.

Comment: I think lsolve would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function `f` as follows which does the calculations of your equation

```
f <- function(alpha) {
    y <- numeric(length(alpha))

    z <- matrix(alpha,nrow=k)
    # or as.numeric((t(z) %*% sd - rd))
    y <- - ((t(z) %*% sd - rd)[1,1]/delta^2) * matrix(sd,nrow=k) - solve(sigma) %*% (z - mu)
    y
}
```

Note: the expression you gave in `R` had at least one mistake; `delta` should have been `delta^2`.

Create some fake data:

```
# some fake data
set.seed(401)
k <- 3
sd <- runif(k)
rd <- runif(k)
delta <- 1
rd <- .04
mu <- 1

sigma <- matrix(runif(k*k,1,4),nrow=k,ncol=3)
sigma
alpha <- rep(1,k)
```

Show the value of `f` for this constellation of variables

```
f(alpha)
```

Use a non linear equation solver to solve for `alpha` as follows

```
library(nleqslv)
nleqslv(alpha,f)
```

If you are going to evaluate `f` many times it is advisable to compute `solve(sigma)` (the inverse of `sigma`) once beforehand.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer

Answer (score 0):

We want

```
((alpha'*s - r)*s)/(d*d) + inv(Sigma)*(alpha - mu)
```

noting that

```
alpha'*s = s'*alpha
```

we can rearrange to

```
(s*s')*alpha/(d*d) -r*s/(d*d) + inv(Sigma)*alpha - inv(Sigma)*mu
```

and then to

```
(inv(Sigma) + (s*s')/(d*d))*alpha = (r/(d*d))*s + inv(Sigma)*mu
```

so

```
alpha = inv( (inv(Sigma) + (s*s')/(d*d)))* ( (r/(d*d))*s + inv(Sigma)*mu)
```

Comment: I don't think your expression is correct. You appear to be assuming that   `t(s) %*%alpha) * s` can be written as `s %*% t(s) * alpha`. Have you tried to use my fake data?

Comment: It can be so written. s and alpha are vectors so s'*alpha is a scalar, which commutes with everything